# Is there a way to automatically convert the \ symbol to the / in java on netbeans on a textfield

Tags: java

Is there a way to automatically convert the \ symbol to the / in java on netbeans on a textfield. The purpose of this is to upload images to a database. I am getting an image location through the file chooser and then im outputting the location (address) to a textfield which then the user can upload through a click of a button. Basically I want to convert the String variable "info" every \ into a / before i set the AddressText

my code is

```
     int returnVal = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(this);

     if (returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
     File file = fileChooser.getSelectedFile();

        // What to do with the file, e.g. display it in a TextArea
       String info =file.getAbsolutePath();

       AddressText.setText(info);

      }
```

Comment: And why would you have to do such a conversion?

Comment: I still don't see why you want to change your \ for /

Comment: @Traroth could be useful in building a remote url for the file to be uploaded to

Comment: java has a "file.separator" in the system properties. Not sure if this is what you are looking for though

Comment: just say for example an image location on your computer would be "C:\Images\test.jpg" where as on Java it would have to be     "C:/Images/test.jpg" if you write to a new line its "\n". the "\" seems to have a different effect. If i write information to an from the database it always has to be "/"

Comment: @ControlAltDel: then he want to transform a Windows path into an URL, which is completly different.

Answer (score 0):

I have done similar things using DocumentListener. When you get an update, you can search for / and replace it.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/event/DocumentListener.html

Document listener has 3 methods. You really only need to implement 2 - the remove / delete one you can leave blank

On the others, when you receive a message that the document is changed, you should call getText() on your textfield, find / replace your characters, and call setText with the modified text

Comment: thank you u seem to understand what i want how would i go about using DocumentListener

Comment: no sorry cant even find what you are talking bout. Surely there is an easy way

Comment: @user1456935 I have given you the answer. Its up to you to put some effort into implementing it

Comment: This kind of approach would only make sense if you want to react immediately as the user types a '\' and convert it to '/', so '\' never shows on screen. Judging from your question this doesn't seem to be your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

You always have the possiblity to use

`... stringMyPath.replaceAll("\\","/");`

but Java manage well this problem.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't have to be a / to work in Java. It's just more convenient sometimes to use / because \ must be escaped in some cases because it has special meaning.

It sounds like your database requires you to escape \ characters when you build an INSERT or UPDATE string. You shouldn't be doing this. You should be using a parameterized query. If you use a parameterized query this then you should not have to escape text and you won't be vulnerable to SQL injection attacks. In Java you would use the PreparedStatement object to do this.